# How to define a variable from an enum?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to define a variable like this:

```
import UIKit

var str1 = "Apple"
var str2 = "Pear"
var str3 = "Kiwi"

enum Algorithm {

    case Algorithm1
    case Algorithm2
    case Algorithm3

}

var chooseAlgorithm {

switch Algorithm {

    case .Algorithm1:
        return str1
    case .Algorithm2:
        return str2
    case .Algorithm3:
        return str3

}

}
```

I tried to run this code on a playground, there were so many errors, interestingly, if I try one of the fix-its prompted by Xcode, XCODE WILL CRASH.

I need to give the value of `str` to `chooseAlgorithm`, how do I achieve that?

Comment: What is `chooseAlgorithm` supposed to do?

Comment: You cannot switch on the type `Algorithm` you have to switch on an instance.

Comment: @Code I want to be able to use `chooseAlgorithm.Algrithm1` to get the value of str, for example.

Comment: @vadian what do you mean by `instance`? Isn't that something of a class?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import UIKit

var str1 = "Apple"
var str2 = "Pear"
var str3 = "Kiwi"

enum Algorithm {
    case Algorithm1
    case Algorithm2
    case Algorithm3

    func chooseAlgorithm() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Algorithm1:
            return str1
        case .Algorithm2:
            return str2
        case .Algorithm3:
            return str3
        }
    }
}

Algorithm.Algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm()
```

Comment: I tried it  and it said `enums may not contain stored properties`

Comment: @BrightFuture See my post edit. This is the full code. Remove everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch on the type `Algorithm` you have to switch on an instance.

And as you need a parameter to pass the `Algorithm` instance, you can't use a variable.

```
func chooseAlgorithm(algorithm : Algorithm) -> String  {

    switch algorithm {

       case .Algorithm1:
           return "I'm Algorithm 1"
       case .Algorithm2:
           return "I'm Algorithm 2"
       case .Algorithm3:
           return "I'm Algorithm 3"

     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vadian, I really want to accept both answers but, since @Code 's answer has the help of auto-completion, I'm gonna accept his ^_^